# Running one testcase in parallel in remote machine and local machine using @Test annotation

Tags: selenium

```
Hi Everyone,

I want to run one testcase in two different machines parallel with different combinations of OS and Browser. But when iam running it is running in remote machine only but parallel..How to run in two machines in parallel?

I am using the below code to make it happen.

Running in Chrome browser in Remote machine in 5556 port
     @Test
    public void inChrome() throws MalformedURLException {

    DesiredCapabilities capability = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
    // Setting the browser
    capability.setBrowserName(BrowserType.CHROME);
    // Setting the platform
    capability.setPlatform(Platform.WINDOWS);
    // Running in the remote machine.
    WebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL(
        "http://192.167.78.89:5556/wd/hub"), capability);
    driver.get("https://www.google.co.in/");
     driver.close();

    }

// Running in firefox browser in local machine where hub is running
    @Test
    public void inFirefox() throws MalformedURLException {
    DesiredCapabilities capability = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
    // Setting the browser
    capability.setBrowserName(BrowserType.FIREFOX);
    // Setting the platform
    capability.setPlatform(Platform.WINDOWS);
    // Running in the local machine.
    WebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL(
        "http:// :4444/wd/hub"), capability);
    driver.get("https://www.google.co.in/");
    driver.close();

    }

and i have testing.xml file

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<suite name="classname" verbose="3">
  <test name="Test" parallel="methods" thread-count="3">
    <classes>
      <class name="packagename.classname"/>
    </classes>
  </test> <!-- Test -->
</suite> <!-- Suite -->
```

When i am running the testing.xml file as TestNG both of the scripts are running on the remote machine(192.167.78.89) only...How i will run the script in local machine and remote machine parallel.

Can someone help me out how to make it possible?

Thanks,

Sudhansu

Answer (score 0):

One of your test should point local browser. If we change inFirefox() to do that, it will be like the following:

```
@Test
public void inFirefox() throws MalformedURLException {
// Running in the local machine.
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.get("https://www.google.co.in/");
driver.close();

}
```

Will this work?

Comment: Thanks Sitam, it is not working...After writing the above code it is opening Chrome in local machine after that it is opening in ff browser in remote machine...which is not my requirement..i need to run the script in parallel in both remotely and locally